# what does this notation mean: $f^{(1,0)}(x,t)$?

Tags: functions, notation

For a bivariate function $f(x,t)$, what does this notation mean: $f^{(1,0)}(x,t)$

Comment: What is the context?  I have seen it mean $f_x(x,t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t)$ but without knowing context, I can't be sure.

Comment: All right, then yes, it means $f_x(x,t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's a standard notation. Nevertheless one can see in some papers and books the notation :
$$\frac{\partial^{n+m}f(x,y)}{\partial^n x\:\partial^m y}\equiv f^{(n,m)}(x,y) $$
which is also used by WolframAlpha.

From the context, this is consistent with :
$$ f^{(1,0)}(x,y) \equiv \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$$

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that notation means $f_x (x,t)$ which means the partial derivative of $ f(x,t)$ .